# ¿Cual es el mejor metodo para encriptar la contraseña al hacer login?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Estoy desarrollando una API genérica con nodejs para autentificarse, y me ha invadido una gran duda a la hora de encriptacion de la contraseña.

No se exactamente cuando encriptarla, si en el la parte frontend en la backend o en la propia base de datos MySQL.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Indice, bienvenido a [es.so]. Recuerda pasar por el [Tour] y [ask] para saber como funciona este sitio. En mi opinion, esta pregunta es *basada en opiniones* ya que las preguntas han de ser objetivas y tu duda es  "cual es el mejor metodo". Eso es muy general, para cada persona puede ser uno u otro, incluso para una persona puede ser distinto dada la situacion especifica del problema. Intenta dar los requisitos que necesitas que cumpla para que te puedan decir de manera objetiva si ese sistema de encriptado es el adecuado. Un saludo

Comment: Creo que la mejor opcion es usar encriptación en el sevidor y en la BD. Para el cliente creo que ya es bastante seguridad usar SSL. Gracias por la respuestas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende del nivel de seguridad que quieres que tengan tus contraseñas:

1. Si lo encriptas en el cliente. Todo el mundo puede ver el código fuente y averiguar como encriptas.
2. Si la contraseña no viaja desde el cliente hasta el servidor por HTTPS, un firewall, proxy, sniffer, etc. podría capturarla.
3. Si en el servidor alguien no autorizado ha instalado un sniffer o tiene un log de todas las queries que se lanzan sobre bbdd podría capturarla.

Cuantas más capas de seguridad pongas mejor. Yo normalmente uso HTTPS  + [aes_encrypt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) en mysql. Pero lo mejor sería encriptarlo en cliente + HTTPS + Encriptarlo en lenguaje de Servidor (PHP/Java/Ruby/etc.) y finalmente encriptarlo en MySQL como el ejemplo a continuación:

Creo una tabla con usuario, el pass y el key(clave)

[image: pantallazo]

Inserto un registro con un campo clave(key) distinto para cada usuario

```
INSERT INTO USUARIO (USER, PASS, CLAVE) VALUES ('PEPE', AES_ENCRYPT('my-secret-password', 'my_key_1'), 'my_key_1');
```

Para consultar

```
SELECT * FROM USUARIO 
WHERE AES_ENCRYPT('my-secret-password', USUARIO.CLAVE) = PASS 
AND USUARIO.USER = 'PEPE';
```

Comment: Si lo encriptas en el cliente.... ¿para que demoños lo encriptas?.. moraleja: nunca confies en el cliente.

Comment: @EmanuelVe , considera que No todos los clientes tendran conocimientos suficientes de informatica o de maldad(xD) para revisar la codificacion y obtener contraseñas

Comment: @Victor-Random solo se necesita uno. Lo que dije medio en broma es que no tiene sentido encriptarlo en el cliente. si averiguan o no como lo encriptas es irrelevante porque en criptologia una premisa basica es "algoritmo publico/clave secreta", que implica que debes asumir que tu enemigo conoce el algoritmo de encriptacion que utilizas y la clave del secreto esta en proteger las claves (no el algoritmo).. Lo que cuenta es que si te envian la clave encriptada en SS nunca tienes acceso a la clave real, solo a un hash de esta.

Comment: @EmanuelVe entiendo tener tu tambien malicia jajajaa :) , entiendo entieno.

Comment: @EmanuelVe justo leia esto: https://blog.capacityacademy.com/2013/08/16/seguridad-informatica-cifrado-simetrico-asimetrico-hashing/

Answer (score 1):

Por seguridad, la contraseña debe viajar siempre encriptada y almacenarla de la misma manera.

Tu API debería aceptar la contraseña ya encriptada y comparar contraseñas encriptadas para poder validar al usuario.

La contraseña almacenada en el MySQL por supuesto que debe estar encriptada.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, la responsabilidad de cifrar la contraseña debería ser de la aplicación y no de la base de datos. Por otra parte, y como han comentado los demás, deberías utilizar SSL para garantizar que en la capa de transporte la contraseña viaja cifrada; no tiene sentido cifrarla desde el lado del cliente.